# Limit remote access to my windows server

Tags: windows, remote-access

Is there a way to limit remote access to my computer (windows 7) only to certain pc?

Now I'm using vnc that use ip filter, but with dynamic dns account, people can access from different point...

Comment: Do some basic research on Windows firewall rules. This information shouldn't be hard to find.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to limit remote access to my computer (windows 7) only to certain pc?

Yes, the Windows-Firewall. It would be interesting to hear, what you mean by 'remote access'. RDP? RPC? WMI?

> Now I'm using vnc that use ip filter, but with dynamic dns account, people can 
>   access from different point...

Dynamic DNS is just a technique to *resolve* IP-Adresses. Your IP-Filter will work anyway.